# How to Avoid changing orders in linq sequence concat

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, sequence, concatenation

I have two sequences defined with var same as below:

```
var seqA = from a in db.aSample
where ([some conditions])
orderby (a.sortOrder)
select new { id = a.id, [... another fields] });

var seqB = from b in db.bSample
where ([some conditions])
orderby (b.sortOrder)
select new { id = b.id, [... another fields] });
```

Then I want to concatenate them to get a new sequence like this:

> { a1, a2, a3, ...., b1, b2, b3, ...}

In real case first sequence (here seqA) has one element and the second sequence (here seqB) has many. I did concatenate like this:

```
var concatSeq = seqA .Concat(seqB);
```

I got concatenated sequence but result just changing sort orders of second sequence (here seqB). I don't know why this strange behavior occurred?

Comment: Sounds like both queries and your `Concat` are being evaluated together at the same time, instead separately. If that's the case then realize `seqA` and `seqB` before concatenating them.

Comment: @DavidG in theory you right. I amazed with this strange behavior as I said.

Comment: @JSteward I realized sequences with AsEnumerable() then concatenated them. Result from concat just the same as before changed the orders of seqB elements.

Comment: How did you use `AsEnumerable`? It might matter if they are queryables.

Comment: @DavidG you right. Sequence load from a table with the parent/child relationship between records. seqA has parent item and I want to be in the first position in result sequence and seqB has child elements. I want to preserve child elements order after concat. this is a brief simple explanation of scenario. I can't upload part of a huge .net project, but If you need more description I must create some snippet in SQL and .net fiddle.

Comment: @DavidG just seqB.AsEnumerable();

Comment: Try it with `seqA.AsEnumerable()` instead, that will force it to use the correct method and evaluate it locally.

Comment: @DavidG seqA just has a single element has own sort order I don't want to calculate here but I'll give a try.

Answer (score 2):

Because both `seqA` and `seqB` are `IQueryable<>`, the `Concat` method being called is the [System.Linq.**Queryable**.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than [System.Linq.**Enumerable**.Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.7.2). It's a subtle difference but it makes the difference. The queryable version will produce SQL something like this, notice there is no ordering specified at all:

```
SELECT ...
FROM SomeTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT ...
FROM SomeTable
```

You can force it to use the enumerable version by using `AsEnumerable()`. For example:

```
var concatSeq = seqA.AsEnumerable().Concat(seqB);
```

Note: *Not* on the inner sequence, the `AsEnumerable` must be on the first sequence. That will produce 2 SQL queries with your ordering, something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

And the concatenation will be done locally in memory. The enumerable version of `Concat` literally loops through the first list, yield returning each item in order, then does the same for the second list. You can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/60a4f8b853f60a424e36c7bf60f9b5b5f1973ed1/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L806).

Comment: Thanks, dud. I'm so sorry for my late. I need a solution emergent and post this question just after I didn't find a usable solution but after discussion with @DavidG I found maybe that is more strange than I thought, So I tried an express cafe solution and solved my issue because of seqA just has one element. I need to find a better solution because other problems most probably have more elements in seqA, Furthermore, I curious to know why thهس strange [in my idea] happened? I faced with a Stubborn grip bacteria about one week and today I could to stand by and check the article.

Comment: One thing It comes to my brain is I tested simultaneous solution with AsQuaryable() after seqB (because I have just one element in seqA as I said) and is not working. For now, I should back to my bed for recovery ;D but I will check it in a first work day and write about the result and what I learned :) Thanks again.